# Создание новой базы данных OleDB

Tags: база-данных, .net, visual-studio, c#

Как создать новую базу данных OleDB (.mdb) C# ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать DAO или ADOX. В проект добавить ссылку на Microsoft ADO Extensions for DDL and Security. Например:

```
using System;
using ADOX;

namespace Test
{
    class Creation
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ADOX.CatalogClass cat = new ADOX.CatalogClass();

            cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                   "Data Source=C:\database.mdb;" +
                   "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");

            Console.WriteLine("База данных создана успешно");

            cat = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, все работает! но мне нужно создавать в этой базе данных еще таблицы с полями! подскажите, пожалуйста, как???

Comment: Посмотрите пример (OleDbSample.cs): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452(v=vs.71).aspx